# Arduino: how to create an ALARM CLOCK with an arduino

Tags: timer, arduino, clock, alarm

Arduino virgin here so be gentle. 
Im trying to create an alarm clock system using an arduino that at the push of a button, sounds an alarm and then when the 'alarm clock' is lifted up it disconnects the alarm clock and starts a timer that sounds another alarm after 3minutes...

What kind of hardware should i be looking at buying to make my dreams come true?

Cheers.

Comment: Try here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/ Based on your description you need a button some resistor, a buzzer and your arduino card. You can add screen to show the time left before next buzz

Answer (score 0):

the easiest and cheapest way to do this is to use a **button**, a **piezo buzzer**, and **2 resistors**. Then build [this circuit](http://reboot.yoha.co.uk/images/thumb/a/ae/AAC_button_full.jpg/800px-AAC_button_full.jpg). the button is connected as a digitalInput, the piezo buzzer is connected to a PWM pin as a analogOutput.